# How to solve the equality $|x−y|=|x|−|y|$ given that both $x$ and $y$ are of same sign and $|x|>|y|$

Tags: inequality

I have tried using the method of 
$|x| = |x-y+y| < |x-y| + |y|$

so $|x| - |y| < |x - y|$

But the above statement not right coz the greater than sign comes in because of Triangle inequality

Comment: The title presents an equality.

Comment: thank you sir. I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two cases

- $x,y>0 \quad |x|>|y| \implies x>y$

  $$|x−y|=x-y=|x|-|y|$$
- $x,y<0 \quad |x|>|y| \implies x<y$

  $$|x−y|=y-x=|x|-|y|$$

Comment: Hi sir thank you for answering. I just wanted to know will it not give a different outcome since |x| - |y| is not equal to |y| - |x| right?

Comment: @RiRi Ops sorry there was  a typo for the second one!

Comment: @RiRi The fact is that $|x-y|=|y-x|>0$ and for $x$ and $y$ with the same sign assuming $|x|>|y|$ we have $|x-y|=|x|-|y|$.

Comment: Aaah i see now, thank you very much sir

Comment: @RiRi To convince yourself let try with $x=4$ and $y=3$ for the first case and $x=-4$ and $y=-3$ for the second one.

Comment: @RiRi You are welcome! Bye

Comment: x = 4 and y = 3 so |4- 3| = |3-4|= 1 which is ofc greater than 0

Answer (score 1):

We can assume that $x\ge 0$ and $y\ge 0$.

then

$$|x|>|y|\implies x>y$$
$$ \implies |x-y|=x-y=|x|-|y|$$

it is always satisfied.